# django forms as a pop up dialogue

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I just created a django form using this following documentation:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/

My Forms.py is similar to this:

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

My Html template is similar to this (from django doc):

```
<dialog id="addForm">
    <form action="{% url "listing" %}" method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

    <input id="task_submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</dialog>

<button onlick="PopUp()">Add Listing </button>

<script>

function PopUp(){
    document.getElementByID("addForm").showModal();
}

</script>
```

However, I want my form to be a pop up dialogue when a user clicks on a button called "add tasks". I do not want the form to show until the user clicks a button called "add tasks". I have not been able to find any methods so far to do so while using Django Forms.

Question: How do I implement a pop up dialogue to display my current django form when a user clicks on a button?

Comment: Thats because you need to put the form in a modal

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: @Brandon Question: How do I implement a pop up dialogue to display my current django form when a user clicks on a button?

Comment: Are you using a presentation layer framework like Twitter Bootstrap of Zurb Foundation?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you use Django. Try searching for "javascript modal" to get some ideas and then put your form into such a modal.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev I've been trying but I still have no luck displaying the form when I click on the button

Comment: Where is `.showModal()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution I was looking for here:

http://blog.raventools.com/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/